# OOP bank database

Tags: java, object-oriented

I have been working on this:

> Design a class for a bank database. The database should support the
>   following operations:
>
> ❍ deposit a certain amount into an account
>
> ❍ withdraw a certain amount from an account
>
> ❍ get the balance (i.e., the current amount) in an account
>
> ❍ transfer an amount from one account to another
>
> The amount in the transactions is a value of type double. The accounts
>   are identified by instances of the class Account that is in the
>   package **com.megabankcorp.records**. The database class should be
>   placed in a package called **com.megabankcorp.system**. The deposit,
>   withdraw, and balance operations should not have any implementation,
>   but allow subclasses to provide the implementation. The transfer
>   operation should use the deposit and withdraw operations to implement
>   the transfer. It should not be possible to alter this operation in any
>   subclass, and only classes within the package
>   **com.megabankcorp.system** should be allowed to use this operation. The deposit and withdraw operations should be accessible in all
>   packages. The balance operation should only be accessible in
>   subclasses and classes within the package **com.megabankcorp.system**.

And this is the implementation:

**Bank.java**

```
package com.megabankcorp.system;

import java.util.List;

import com.megabankcorp.records.Account;

public abstract class Bank {

    public abstract void depositAmount(Account account, double amount);
    public abstract void withdrawAmount(Account account, double amount);
    protected abstract double currentBalance(Account account);

    List<Account> accounts; //Can be more than one account.

    boolean transferAmount(Bank bank, Account transferFrom, Account transferTo, double amount) {
        boolean isTransferred = false;
        if (transferFrom.getAccountNumber() == transferTo.getAccountNumber()) {
            System.out.println("Can not transfer in your own account.");
        } else if (transferFrom.getCurrentAmount() < amount) {
            System.out.println("You have insufficient funds.");
        } else {
            bank.depositAmount(transferTo, amount);
            bank.withdrawAmount(transferFrom, amount);
            isTransferred = true;
        }
        return isTransferred;
    }
}
```

**ABC.java**

```
package com.megabankcorp.system;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.megabankcorp.records.Account;

public class ABC extends Bank {

    public ABC () {
        this.accounts = new ArrayList<Account>();
    }

    @Override
    public void depositAmount(Account account, double amount) {
        account.setCurrentAmount(account.getCurrentAmount() - amount);
    }

    @Override
    public void withdrawAmount(Account account, double amount) {
        account.setCurrentAmount(account.getCurrentAmount() - amount);
    }

    @Override
    protected double currentBalance(Account account) {
        return account.getCurrentAmount();
    }



}
```

**Account.java**

```
package com.megabankcorp.records;


public class Account {

    private int accountNumber;
    private double currentAmount;

    public Account (int accountNumber) {
        this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
    }

    public int getAccountNumber() {
        return accountNumber;
    }

    public double getCurrentAmount() {
        return currentAmount;
    }

    public void setCurrentAmount(double amount) {
        this.currentAmount = amount;
    }
}
```

Please suggest the best practice possible for this problem. Any suggestions and ideas are welcome.

Comment: This is an elementary school problem. It's like asking for best practices to add 2 and 2 together.

Comment: Is that really so?

Comment: @PM77-1 Do you think this code is perfect then?

Comment: It should be noted that for actual financial software, [you shouldn't use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency) `double`, instead use `BigDecimal`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Emphases added in quotes below.

> Design **a** class for a bank database.

Write **one** class. The rest should be stubbed just enough to make the 
main thing you are writing compile. Especially there should not be a class `ABC`.

> Design a class for a **bank database**.

If it is called "bank database" in the requirements, why the class is 
named `Bank`.

> It should not be possible to alter this operation in any subclass

They ask you to make `transfer` method `final`, which you did not.

> transfer an amount from one account to another

There is "an amount", "from one account", "to another", where did you 
get the `Bank bank` argument in the `transfer` method. If I'm invoking a method on an instance, I do not expect to pass the object to itself; use `this` instead.

Also there is no mention of that method returning anything. Methods that indicate actions 
or commands etc should declare return type `void`, whenever possible.

Use appropriate exceptions instead of returning error codes. Change the 
types of exceptions as you learn more about exception handling:

```
if (transferFrom.getAccountNumber() == transferTo.getAccountNumber())
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can not transfer in your own account.");

if (transferFrom.getCurrentAmount() < amount)
    throw new IllegalStateException("You have insufficient funds.");

this.depositAmount(transferTo, amount);
this.withdrawAmount(transferFrom, amount);
```

The requirement says "transfer" "from one account" "to another 
[account]", but you `transfer` `transferFrom` `transferTo`, that doesn't read well at all. Rename them `fromAccount` and `toAccount`.

There is nothing mentioned about 
`.getAccountNumber()`, or about account numbers being comparable by `==`. 
It probably should be something like `fromAccount.equals(toAccount)`. 
And what two accounts being equal means should be defined in `Account.equals()`
(which you needn't write yet, which is always something good).
Also requirement says:

> The accounts are **identified by** instances of the class Account

`Account` class appears to be a --badly named-- identifier. We don't know that `balance` is in it, and not in some other class "identified by ... Account", say `AccountRecord`. The gist is you don't know, and you don't need to know. (Not needing something is better that needing something. Therefore not needing to know is better than needing to know. OOP is focused a lot on reducing the amount of things you need to know.)

Also just lose the `List<Account> accounts;` field. There is nothing about it in the requirements.

Comment: Really, thanks a lot. I am so glad that you took time to read my problem and help me, that's really helping.